# How to externalize i18n properties files in spring-boot applications

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, string-externalization

I’ve succeed to externalize my spring-boot configuration file (`application.properties`) in a `config` folder when I run my spring-boot application as a unix service with the help of the official spring documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

I have also some i18n `messages.properties` files in my `src/main/resources` that I would like to externalize in the same config folder but I failed to do it. I’ve tried a lot of things, like playing with `spring.messages.basename` but unfortunately, it doesn’t work.

I’m using the latest version of spring-boot, and use auto configure mode with the default i18n properties name `messages`.

What am I missing??? thanks for your help.

Comment: i've try : 
`spring.messages.basename=classpath:messages`
or
`spring.messages.basename=classpath*:messages`
assuming spring config directory is on the classpath. maybe i'm wrong?

Comment: Well yeah the config or anything outside of the jar isn't on the classpath. Next to that then it would have to be `config/messages` as a base name instead.

Comment: @M. Deinum i've tried `spring.messages.basename=config/messages`but spring can't find the translation if i do that.

Comment: and what about `classpath:config/messages`?

Comment: spring.messages.basename=file:config/messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a few notes:

1. **classpath:message** - will always lookup embeded message_xxx files
2. **classpath:/message** and **classpath:message** are equivalent
3. **file:message** - will lookup jar's external current directory e.g. ./message_en.properties <- this is what you want
4. **file:/message** - you have to put your message files to root "/" to make it work
5. use notation **file:config/message** if you need to put in config folder together with your
   ./config/application.properties

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a leading slash.

Try: `spring.messages.basename=classpath:/config/messages`

Answer (score 0):

I think, resource bundle is default to classpath. So there's no need to append it. just go straight to your folder location from classpath.

Try this: **assuming your config is inside static folder

spring.messages.basename=static/config/messages